# How to enable code assist for Solr in php using ZendStudio

Tags: php, eclipse, solr, zend-studio

I have just installed the Solr extension for php and I'm trying to set ZendStudio to recognize the lib so I can get code assist for it.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102205/code-completion-for-php-extensions-in-zend-studio) that I should put a stub file for the library in the path, but I couldn't find such a file, and before I code it myself... here I am. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1. Download last solr here http://pecl.php.net/package/solr
2. Unpack it
3. You need file like /solr-x.x.x/docs/documentation.php
4. Include this file to your project