# Zend Studio 13: Memcached class not found

Tags: php, memcached, zend-studio

My Zend Studio 13 does know the Memcache but not the Memcached class. I tried to switch between different PHP executables but nothing fixed this problem for me. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had to generate the stub file for memcached by myself. This answer helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/8258073/2228349